# control checkbox value to hide text box in Windows Installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer

I am creating a installer using Visual Studio set up project. Based on the checkbox input I want to control textbox show/hide. Is there any way I can do that? Thanks.

During installation process installer will ask What kind of SQL authentication User want? Windows or SQL. Based on checkbox value text box will appear asking for connectionString value, user name, password which will modify .exe.config.

Comment: I have two textbox indicating two different scenario. If user choose Window, it will ask for connection string otherwise it willl ask for server name , user id password.

Answer (score 0):

if i did understand your question right , then you can use

```
TextBox.PasswordChar Property
```

by sitting a character like : `*`

then whenever you want to show the content of the textbox reset that character to `null`